# Сортировка матрицы. Как отсортировать матрицу выбором? Selection sort на С++

Tags: c++, функции, матрицы

1.Разработать функцию на C++ методом "selection sort".
2.Создать матрицу (2х12) и заполнить её случайными числами.
3.Сделать сортировку матрицы , используя разработанную функцию.

Помогите пожалуйста , буду очень благодарен)

C++

#include 
using namespace std;

int main()
{

```
const int n=12;
int a[n][n];
//Ввод элементов
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        cout << "Vvedite element a[" << i << "][" << j << "] ";
        cin >> a[i][j];
        cout << endl;
    }


int min = 0;    // для записи минимального значения
int buf = 0;    // для обмена значениями

/*********** Начало сортировки **************/
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    min = i; // запомним номер текущей ячейки, как ячейки с минимальным значением
    // в цикле найдем реальный номер ячейки с минимальным значением
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        min = ( a[j] < a[min] ) ? j : min;
    // cделаем перестановку этого элемента, поменяв его местами с текущим
    if (i != min)
    {
        buf = a[i];
        a[i] = a[min];
        a[min] = buf;
    }
}
/*********** Конец сортировки **************/

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)     //Вывод отсортированного массива
    cout << a[i] << '\t';
cout << endl;
```

}

Comment: int j = i + 1; j < n; j++, может тут должно быть int j =1? Иначе, я не понимаю в чём смысл этого.

Comment: нуу там в коде ошибку выбивает как раз на перестановке я не понимаю почему , там где 'buf'

Comment: Ну вы ищете минимум, потом записываете его в j. А само условие проверяете по i. Не понятно почему.  К тому же в задании размер 2 на 12, у вас 12 на 12 в коде. Вывод тоже странный.

Comment: Обращение к двумерному массиву по одному индексу происходит. Может я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Как сортировать матрицу? Сортируем строки, столбы, или все элементы матрицы слева направо, сверху вниз, или как-то иначе?

Comment: все элементы матрицы слева направо

Comment: много ответов на эту тему. Смотрите например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/525504/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc

Comment: `все элементы матрицы слева направо` Данная формулировка допускает неоднозначную трактовку. Сформулируйте подробнее.

Comment: Нам не говорили как именно , сказали просто отсортировать это часть курсовой , я думаю что как угодно только бы был этот метод и все.